# SSRS report show static headers on the left and group by ID

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following DataSet on a SSRS report:

```
SELECT
  VariationCode.Code
  ,VariationCoding.Comment
  ,VariationCoding.SubmissionDate
  ,VariationCoding.Id
FROM
  VariationCode
  INNER JOIN VariationCoding
    ON VariationCode.Id = VariationCoding.VariationCodeId
WHERE VariationId = @VariationId
```

I am showing static headers on the left and data on the right which works fine but I'm struggling to group the results by ID and show them as a separate table per grouping.

Grouping the row by parent using VariationCoding.Id shows one table with no grouping at all. I suspect having the headers on the left is the problem since most solutions I've seen have the headers on top.

How can I show static headers on the left and group the results by VariationCoding.Id in such a way that each result will be displayed in a separate table?

Comment: can you show us your Design and your current results. This will help us understand issue more.
BTW I created Report header and added TextBox on to extreme Top left and used grouping for my table it worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a list control to solve the problem as described on Microsoft docs - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-invoices-and-forms-with-lists-report-builder-and-ssrs

> A list data region repeats with each group or row in the Reporting
>   Services paginated report dataset. A list can be used to create
>   free-form reports or forms, such as invoices, or in conjunction with
>   other data regions. You can define lists that contain any number of
>   report items.

By creating a table with static columns on the left and nesting it inside the list control, I was able to bind the table data columns to the list data source and this grouped my custom table per record.

Answer (score 0):

> group the results by ID and show them as a separate table per grouping.

You may want try **Page break** option, from **Group Properties**, screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: tried it but didn't work. I ended up placing the table inside a list and that worked perfectly.